# calculating mean of a list into sub-lists

Tags: python, statistics

If I have a big list or numpy array or etc that I need to split into sub-lists, how could I efficiently calculate the stadistics (mean, standar deviation, etc) for the whole list?

As a simple example, let's say that I have this small list:

```
l = [2,1,4,1,2,1,3,2,1,5]
>>> mean(l)
2.2000000000000002
```

But, if for some reason I need to split into sub-lists:

```
l1 = [2,1,4,1]
l2 = [2,1,3,2]
l3 = [1,5]
```

Of course, you don't need to know a lot about mathematics to know that this is **NOT TRUE:**

```
mean(l) = mean(mean(l1), mean(l2), mean(l3))
```

This may be true just if the lenght of all and every list is the same, which is not in this case.

The background of this question is related to the case when you have a very big dataset that does not fit into memory, and thus, you will need to split it into chucks.

Comment: you could maybe store the data on disk, with [numpy.memmap](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html).

Comment: have you checked pandas?

Comment: @user3570335, need more than a simple question as an answer!!

Comment: I don't see any code that i can help you here ... If you post code ... It would help in understanding the issue

Comment: @user3570335 read it twice, this is not a code-related question, this is more a "concept" question, of course there is not any code in my question, just because I do not know how to implement it....the only "code" that I have is what you see in the question.

Comment: This is code related forum.. not for math questions.. With this attitude .. I really hope you would find someone that can help you

Answer (score 2):

In general, you need to keep the so-called sufficient statistics for each subset. For the mean and standard deviation, the sufficient statistics are the number of data, their sum, and their sum of squares. Given those 3 quantities for each subset, you can compute the mean and standard deviation for the whole set.

The sufficient statistics are not necessarily any smaller than the subset itself. But for mean and standard deviation, the sufficient statistics are just a few numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you know the number of data points you have, i.e., len(l)? Then you could just calculate a sum of each list indidividually (i.e., Map-reduce) or a running sum (i.e, if you are doing a readline()), and then divide by len(l) at the very end?

Comment: Im not sure if this is 100% correct...you will probably have to divide by the `sum of the lenghts` and add the sum of each sub-list to the next sub-list

Comment: Yes, this is what I said. You would either (i) in parallel calculate the sum of each individual list and then add all these sums together, or (ii) add each list sum to the previous one in a 'running' sum. Then at the very end divide by the total number of elements of all the lists.

Comment: yeah, thanks then, this was my first idea, and that was what I meant when I said something more "efficiet"..if possible.